# Zoom on a two dimensional UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I created a `UICollectionView` which is horizontal and vertically. It has different `UICollectionViewCells`. Everything is layouted correctly. Now I am trying to make it `zoomable`. The `UICollectionViewCells` are resized correctly too. Every time the `UIPinchGesture` occures, I set the `itemSize` inside the `UICollectionViewLayout` dependend on the `scale`.

```
TestLayout *layout =  (TestLayout *) self.collectionViewLayout;
CGSize newItemSize = CGSizeMake(_sizeItem.width * gesture.scale, 
                                _sizeItem.height * gesture.scale);
[layout setItemSize:newItemSize];
```

Here you can see the method **setItemSize** I am calling inside my CustomLayout.

```
- (void)setItemSize:(CGSize)itemSize
{
    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(self.itemSize, itemSize)) return;

    _itemSize = itemSize;

//    [self prepareLayout];
    [self invalidateLayout];
}
```

My problem is know, all items `resize` to the right bottom and I don't know how to focus exactly on the element my `UIPinchGesture` was on.

I tried to change the `contentOffset` every time the `gesture` occures like this:

```
CGPoint posInView = [gesture locationInView:self];
CGPoint pointPinchTouch = CGPointMake(posInView.x - self.contentOffset.x,
                                      posInView.y - self.contentOffset.y);
CGPoint newOffset = CGPointMake(self.contentOffset.x * (gesture.scale * 2),
                                self.contentOffset.y * (gesture.scale * 2));
[self setContentOffset:newOffset animated:NO];
```

But I never managed to stay on the `CGPoint` my `UIPinchGesture` was executed.

Furthermore when `scrolling` on the whole `UICollectionView`, my `contentOffset` is still `{0,0}` when the `scroll` didn't end. So start pinching I always end up in the top left corner.
Because the `UICollectionView` seems not to be designed to be used horizontal and vertical at the same time, thats why I also can't use the `delegate` methods of `UIScrollView` for `zooming`. 
Maybe somebody can tell me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understand the problem. You are trying to zoom in on a specific cell by changing the item size, but the size of ALL the cells are changing instead of the one that was pinched?

If my understanding is correct, then I can help. Changing FlowLayout.itemSize changes the size for all cells in the collection view. If you want to set the item size of specific cells, you should override UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout's sizeForItemAtIndexPath. In the sizeForItemAtIndexPath method, you can check the itemAtIndexPath against the cell that was pinched and return a different size just for that cell.

The other part of your question (about the scrolling and offset) is not really clear to me. You are right that collection views are supposed to be used either horizontally or vertically but not both. Perhaps that is what causes the problem?